# Listing channel entries by parent and siblings

Tags: relationships, navigation, related-entries, reverse-related-entries, list

I have a channel called fruit.
There is a custom field called 'parent' of type 'relationship' in this channel.
The relationship is set to channel fruit.

When I edit my entries in this channel, I can set the field called parent to any of my other entries.

Example entries...

- Orange
- Banana
- Apple
- Pear (parent is Grape)
- Grape
- Lemon (parent is Banana)
- Strawberry (parent is Apple)
- Kiwi (parent is Grape)
- Mango (parent is Apple)

Based on the above, with my setting of some entries to be parents of other entries, a list would appear as...

- Apple

  - Strawberry
  - Mango
- Banana

  - Lemon
- Grape

  - Pear
  - Kiwi
- Orange

Now I want to setup an ordered list to display this relationship **dynamically** so that the generated code results in...

```
<ul>
  <li>Apple
    <ul>
      <li>Strawberry</li>
      <li>Mango</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Banana
    <ul>
      <li>Lemon</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Grape
    <ul>
      <li>Pear</li>
      <li> Kiwi</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Orange</li>
</ul>
```

I have been reading about the new way EE handles parent-child-sibling relationships in the Docs. But I am having problems coding the above.

Cheers

Comment: I guess you can't use 'parent' as name of a field.

Comment: I didn't use the word parent. I used 'site_parent'. I could have named it anything though.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but this *should* work. We're checking to see if each fruit has parents, and if it *doesn't*, then we display it (and any child fruits). It would be helpful if the fieldtype had something like [Playa's](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/playa) `:total_parents` and `:total_children` tags, but it doesn't (which is one of the many reasons I still use Playa).

```
<ul>
{if '{parents field="child_fruit"}{title}{/parents}' == ''}
    <li>
        {title}
        {child_fruit}
        {if child_fruit:count == "1"}<ul>{/if}
            <li>{title}</li>
        {if child_fruit:count == child_fruit:count:total_results}</ul>{/if}
        {/child_fruit}
    </li>
{/if}
</ul>
```